# How to allow specific ports for docker using iptables --> dport uses port within the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, iptables

In the first step I want to block all incoming traffic to the docker containers running on my server. Therefore I use the following iptables entry for the ip of my external interface (ext_if):

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 ! -s ext_if -j DROP
```

Then I want to open a specific port to a container, which is configured in a docker-compose (my docker-compose.yml is below) file:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i docker0 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```

When I try to open http://myserver:9000 in a browser from outside it will not work.

What can I do to configure port 9000 to be accessible from outside?

I am using docker 19.03.2 and docker-compose 1.18.0 on a dedicated server.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  test-tomcat:
    image: tomcat:9.0.19-jre8
    ports:
      - 9000:8080
    container_name: test-tomcat
    restart: always
    entrypoint: catalina.sh jpda run
  test-tomcat2:
    image: tomcat:9.0.19-jre8
    ports:
      - 9001:8080
    container_name: test-tomcat2
    restart: always
    entrypoint: catalina.sh jpda run
```

I played a little bit with iptable rules and figured out, that

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i docker0 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

will give me access to both http://myserver:9000 and http://myserver:9001. I think this is because both containers are listening to 8080 internally.

Comment: The easier way is to set `ports: ['127.0.0.1:9000:8080']`, which will bind the socket to the host's localhost interface only.

Comment: Thank you, I think Davids approach will work, but binding the ports to localhost is dangerous in my opinion. If you forget to bind it to 127.0.0.1 in docker-compose.yml explicitly then the port will be open. I am looking for a general solution which blocks all ports except the ones with special iptables configuration.